# Gambling best strategy question

Tags: probability, gambling

Just came across an interesting question around strategic betting and was wondering if I would be able to get your thoughts on this one:

You can deposit \$1000 on a blackjack website and they will give you \$1000 of credit to match. You can only withdraw once you have bet a total of \$10000 on blackjack hands. Suppose that you expect 90c per \$1 of play. What is the optimal betting strategy?

Here I thought about the fact that if you were to bet a \$1 each time of play, you will be left with nothing (on average) after 10000 rounds as you lose money per round. This is also true if you decide to bet \$2 each round, and same goes for \$3 etc. Therefore, you should bet the whole \$1000 and if you win, you can safely bet \$1 each round to reach the \$10000 target.

Not sure if this is correct so I'm wondering what your thoughts are on this. Thanks!

Comment: You mention winning expectation to be 90%, but what's the upper bound? As in, if I put in (say) 100 dollars, what's the biggest payout aka upper bound ? Certainly the lower bound must be 0 dollars, i.e. I lose all my money.
Because if we assume that the payout is fixed at 90% of the money I put in, then well, no point playing except for the fun yeah?

Comment: It's a blackjack game so suppose that you win the amount equivalent to your bet size (disallowing doubling, splitting, blackjacks etc.)

Comment: Okay, and what's the distribution like between these bounds ? My apologies, I'm not familiar with non-hypothetical card games, so although I can understand the rules of blackjack at a theoretical level, I'm not knowledgeable of how the "bonus"(as listed on wikipedia) scales. Or do you want to state the problem as binary, one either wins double the amount, or loses, with the expected winnings being 90%?